# Set item in onclick is not logging expected output

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing a simple react code that adds a value to a list `onClick` of a button. and after adding, I'm logging it in the same block. Currently, my issue is, that the logging is happening with `n-1` entered string. i.e. If I enter `egg` and then add `milk`, after adding `milk`, I see `egg` logged and so on. Here is my code.

```
function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [gItem, setGItem] = useState("");

  const AddItem = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setList([...list, gItem]);
    console.log(list);
  };
  return (
    <>
         <form className="grocery-form">
          <h3>grocery bud</h3>
          <div className="form-control">
            <label htmlFor="name"></label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="e.g. eggs"
              className="grocery"
              name="name"
              id="name"
              onChange={(e) => setGItem(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button className="submit-btn" type="submit" onClick={AddItem}>
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div className="grocery-container">
          <List items={list} />
        </div>
     </>
  );
}
```

I'm unable to understand where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setList updates state asynchronously so if you log state after using it the previous value will be displayed, to make it log the current state after this list was changed you can use useEffect hook like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(list);
}, [list])
```

Comment: I would also use `setList(prevList => [...prevList, gItem]);` instead of `setList([...list, gItem]);`